# Jquery UI Droppable "not accepted" event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

There's a way to set a function when the draggable is not accepted by the droppable?

For e.g.

The droppables are at a enabled state, when the draggable starts to be drag if they are accepted, the droppables get the "activeClass", if they are'nt accepted, the droppables get the "inactiveClass"(for e.g.)

There's a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Well I had this problem too to execute some function if a draggable isn't accepted by a droppable. After lot of searching I found that you can have functions for a scenario where a draggable is not accepted by the droppable. I found that the draggable option revert can have functions as well other than "true, false, valid, invalid" values.
You can assign a function to revert which will execute even when the draggable is dropped in a droppable and also when it is not dropped on the droppable.

```
$("selector").draggable({
    revert : function(droppableContainer) {
        if(droppableContainer) {
            //if drop is valid i.e. draggable is dropped on a valid droppable or droppable has accepted the draggable
        }
        else {
            //if drop is invalid i.e. droppable has not accepted the draggable
        }
        return(!droppableContainer) //returns true if invalid drop i.e draggable will revert and false if the draggable has been dropped correctly and thus no revert
    }
});
```

Comment: If you have any queries regarding the answer let me know